# MYSQL trigger-change row after update

Tags: php, mysql

What I have:
A MYSQL table in joomla-php, that gives points to someone according to his age and education.

There is a php function after pressing submit button, that says "if dropdown box `age > 30`, then give 5 points. Insert fieldvalue "5" to database row, with `fieldname = 'point-age'` and `'fieldvalue' = 5`.

If `age < 30`, give 10 points" to fieldname 'point-age' , `fieldvalue = '10'`.
 Same for education (high school 5 points, university 10 points, etc).
 Fieldname = education.

Then it adds to a final row, 'fieldname= point-total', 'fieldvalue'= sum of all the others.

[image: example of table image]

My php function:

```
//case for age
switch ($_POST['form']['age'][0]) {

    case 'over 30':
$_POST['form']['point-age'] = 5;
        break;

  case 'less than 30':
$_POST['form']['point-age'] = 10;
break;

}

//case for education
switch ($_POST['form']['education'][0]) {       
    case 'high school':
$_POST['form']['point-education'] = 5;
break; 
    case 'university':
$_POST['form']['point-university'] = 10;
break;
}

//the sum
 $_POST['form']['point-total'] = $_POST['form']
 ['point-age'] + $_POST['form']['point-education'];
```

This works well.

However, what i want to do: after updating a database value, e.g. someone that had a high school degree and got a university degree, or goes after 30, or just correct a mistake. It should be updated automatically. Not updating manually all the corresponding fieldvalues and total values, especially for more fields to come.

I am trying with a database trigger, but it shows the error message:

```
#1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger
```

My current questions:
-What am i doing wrong? 
-How can the trigger be fixed? 
-Is there any better way to do my function, to update the points after a change?

```
CREATE TRIGGER update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if (`FieldName` = 'age' and `FieldValue` = 'less than 30') THEN
set NEW.point-age = 10;
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Change to before update? and fieldname and fieldvalue should be prefixed.

Comment: In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated.

A column named with OLD is read only. You can refer to it (if you have the SELECT privilege), but not modify it. You can refer to a column named with NEW if you have the SELECT privilege for it. In a BEFORE trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW.col_name = value if you have the UPDATE privilege for it. - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Storing the age like this is prone to getting out of date, you should have the date of birth and calculate the age from that.  This also is the same for the points, why store it in the database when it is derived from the data on the record - calculate it when you display it.

Comment: Its ok for the age, that's how it was demanded, to choose between 2 values from a database box.
Furthermore, the joomla "submissions" page does not accept php, that is why i am trying with a database trigger.

Comment: @P.Salmon:

Problem is, there are specific rows in one collumn, not the collumns. Refer to the image.

Comment: SQL isn't designed for this kind of structure.